# Dynamically add items to javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I defined this:

```
var data ={};
```

I want to get somehting like this for each "line" in the object:

```
{field1: "bananas", field2:'test', field3:111, field4:"23.4", field5:"bob"},
{field1: "fruit", field2:'test again', field3:222, field4:"30", field5:"john"}
```

I know I can do this to add dynamic and static data:

```
data['field1']= docType;
    data['field2'] = docRef;
    data['field3'] = "test3";
    data['field4'] = mydynamicdata;
    data['field5'] = "test5";
```

But how can I add different items lines? This code would only add a item set, right? How can I add a second one?

thank you!

Comment: You need an array of objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2):

You need an Array of Objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
var data = [];

data.push({field1: "bananas", field2:'test', field3:111, field4:"23.4", field5:"bob"})
data.push({field1: "fruit", field2:'test again', field3:222, field4:"30", field5:"john"})
```

Then you can make changes like this:

```
data[0]['field1'] = 'new value'
//or:
data[0].field1 = 'new value'
```

Where `0` is the index of the item inside of the list. So `data[1]` would be the second object, and so on...

Comment: hello, This data is to pass to yui datatable. Can it receive that array of objects? By now im passing a data ={};

Comment: actually, according to the docs - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/ - the expected format of data is an Array